# Is there a way to join results from two queries in Python using sqlalchemy engine?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run two sql queries using sqlalchemy engine in python 3.7. However, I am having trouble joining results columns from two queries. Is there an efficient way to perform this for MSSQL?

Following is the table that is being queried

```
timestamp           startX  startY  Number
2019-05-13-10:31    695     384     0
2019-05-13-10:32    3914    256     25ZLH3300MEPACC16x25
2019-05-13-10:32    3911    442     25ZLH3300MEPACC16x25
2019-05-13-10:32    3904    2109    25ZLH3300MEPACC16x25
2019-05-13-10:32    3910    627     25ZLH3300MEPACC16x25
2019-05-13-10:32    3904    1445    25ZLH3300MEPACC16x25
```

and I need to get this as an output

```
timestamp           startX  startY  Number                 Quantity
2019-05-13-10:31    695     384     0                      1
2019-05-13-10:32    3914    256     25ZLH3300MEPACC16x25   5
```

First query returns unique records based on Number as follows

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 
       [timestamp]
      ,[startX]
      ,[startY]
      ,[Number]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by [Table].Number, 
                                    [Table].Number,  
                                    type order by [timestamp] DESC) rownumber 
                                    FROM [Table]) a WHERE rownumber = 1
```

Second query returns count of duplicate records as Quantity column with a Number column.

```
SELECT [Table].Number, count(*) AS 'Quantity'
FROM   [Table]
GROUP  BY [TABLE].Number
HAVING count(*) >= 1
```

I would like to join results from query #1 and column quantity from query #2 based on Number as primary key.

```
connection = engine.connect()
            connection.execute(""" Query """)
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just added the table and the output required to satisfy that requirement

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT * FROM (query1) AS q1 INNER JOIN (query2) AS q2 ON q1.number = q2.number`?

Comment: you can't get the same results always on every run with this example data as SQL tables/resultsets are by ANSI/ISO SQL standard definition orderless..  `ORDER BY timestamp DESC` would still give non deterministic (random) results because the timestamps are not unique.. Do you have a column with `IDENTITY` in your table we need to that to get pure deterministic (fixed) results by adding that also in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I do not have ID column, however the purpose is to retrieve one unique record regardless of how it is ordered to match quantity against. All I want is to display unique records and corresponding quantities.

Comment: *"however the purpose is to retrieve one unique record regardless of how it is ordered to match quantity against. All I want is to display unique records and corresponding quantitie"* fair enough then you can "ignore" mine comment and remember it when the order is important.

Comment: @MatBailie I do not want number to appear twice in the resulting table, which is the case if I do an inner join.

Comment: @Far - That's not caused by the `INNER JOIN`, that's caused by having `type` in your `PARTITION BY`; in other words, the first query already includes the duplicates that you don't want, so fix the first query.

Comment: @MatBailie I removed `SELECT [Number]` from first query, however `rownumber` still appears after the join.

Comment: @Far - Don't remove `Number` from either query, there would  be nothing to join on, just change what you're selecting as your final result...  Replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT q1.Number, q1.timestamp, q1.startX, q1.startY, q2.Quantity`

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, it works! Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 3):

You could just do it in a single query, one example would be:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        [timestamp]
       ,[startX]
       ,[startY]
       ,[Number]
       ,ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Table].Number, 
                               [Table].type
                      ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC
                 )
                   AS rownumber 
       ,COUNT(*)
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Table].Number
                 )
                   AS Quantity
    FROM
      [Table]
)
    a
WHERE
        rownumber = 1
    AND quantity  > 1
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Indeed, but the op wanted to know how to join the queries, not how to fix or validate either query ;)

Comment: very true i removed the comment under this answer because the topicsstarter said the order wasn't important..  +1 by the way the query is valid..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `pandas` and join on DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = slqalchemy.create_enging(my_sql_settings)

df_unique_records = pd.read_sql(sql=my_query_1, conn=engine, index_col=Number)
df_duplicate_counts = pd.read_sql(sql=my_query_2, conn=engine, index_col=Number)

df = df_unique_records.merge(df_duplicate_counts, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know if I could have sql server handle this.